# Whether db data in the iPhone Mobile App will vary on every testing from simulator?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am working on a Xamarin iPhone App. Every time, I launch the App in the simulator,  the data in the App starts from beginning.

To give an example,I have a user registration table. On first time testing, I created an account. On second time, when i tested the app from simulator , i don't see the account. When i looked on the sqlite db , i don't see the record which i inserted.

Sync between Sqlite and SQL Server is not yet done. Right now, I am testing only the Mobile Part of the App.

Is it required to have a sync to have the same data in the Sqlite?

Comment: How do you create your db?  Is it seeded from an existing db file that is deployed with your project, or do you programatically create it when your app starts?

Comment: DB is created separately. I initially created a SQL Database and then exported to SQLite. App is seeded from an existing db file.

Comment: I am new to App Programming. I felt to go with this process. I am not sure, which is the right methodology or architecture

Comment: When you seed from a file, that file will get deployed to the simulator every time you run your app fro the IDE.  Since it is bundled with the app, it will also be read-only.  You will need to copy the db file to a writable directory when your app starts.  Or, you can create the file programatically when the app starts.  Both approaches are valid, depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Jason .. Question is : How would i copy the file to a writable directory and make it as static file ?? That means .. every time app loads, it has to point to the same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Xamarin Forms application? If yes then you can follow my [blog](http://err2solution.com/2016/05/sqlite-with-xamarin-forms-step-by-step-guide/) where I have done a CRUD operation in Xamarin forms to SQLite local database.

Comment: please don't post answers that are just links to other sites

Comment: Thank you for @S Ravi Kumar, I will take a look..

Comment: @Jason I was trying to help him as his question was not that detailed. Anyways will keep it in mind in future